# Push JSON to Angular client with WebSocket

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, websocket

I have a solution that works just fine doing this. However it utilizes $rootScope like so:

```
angularApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.socket = {};
    $rootScope.socket.messages = [];

    var socket = io.connect('/', {});

    socket.on('messages', function (messages) {
        if (! angular.equals($rootScope.socket.messages, messages)) {
            $rootScope.socket.messages = messages;
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    });
}]);
```

According to the last paragraph in the documentation $rootScope is bad practice and is comparable to global variables: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

What is the best practice to do this without the $rootScope? I've tried using a service in combination with $watch but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a SocketService, and provide it through dependency injection to your controllers.

[Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

[Understanding Dependency Injection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection)

Comment: That was my first solution I tried, but how do I get the service to update my local $scope?

Comment: My thought here is, a service is run once and my socket.on() - function is run once. How do i switch the function passed to socket.on() to a function that changes my local $scope? This might be  simple JavaScript question. I have no problems with services or DI.